# Quartz Scheduler интервал повторов не может быть равен 0.

Tags: java, quartz

Использую [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) для установки задач. Ставлю задачу, но на моменте `SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(1)` вылетает эксепшн: `org.quartz.SchedulerException: Repeat Interval cannot be zero.`

Почему это происходит я не могу понять, ведь значение повтора равно 1 а не 0.
В чем может быть штука?

```
CronModel CRON = CronModel.getInstance();
    String IDENTITY = "identity-" + 1 + "-" + 2;
    JobDataMap JobData = new JobDataMap();
    JobData.put("1", 1);
    JobData.put("1", 2);

    JobDetail DETAIL = JobBuilder.newJob(CronCompetitive.class).withIdentity(IDENTITY).setJobData(JobData).build();

    Trigger TRIGGER = newTrigger().withIdentity(IDENTITY).startAt(futureDate(15, DateBuilder.IntervalUnit.MINUTE))
                                    .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(1))
                                    .withPriority(1)
                                    .forJob(IDENTITY)
                                    .build();
CRON.scheduleJobWithData(DETAIL, TRIGGER)
```

Comment: `withRepeatCount` задает количество повторов, вам надо еще задать интервал между повторами (`withIntervalXXX`, [см. документацию](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/SimpleScheduleBuilder.html))

Comment: @zRrr в данном случае мне надо его запустить один раз. я указываю время через которое он должен стартануть - 15 минут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже если Вы хотите запустить задачу всего один раз, необходимо установить интервал между запусками, например `.withIntervalInSeconds(N)`.
По умолчанию, интервал равен 0, что вызывает ошибку при валидации триггера.

Вот такое дополнение должно решить Вашу проблему.

```
SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(1)
    .withIntervalInSeconds(1)
```

В реализации `SimpleTriggetImpl` можно увидеть следующий код:

```
if (repeatCount != 0 && repeatInterval < 1) {
    throw new SchedulerException("Repeat Interval cannot be zero.");
}
```

Отсюда можно сделать вывод, что интервал равный нулю допускается только при нулевом количестве запусков.